# Bitcode error packaging ipa using xcodebuild

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8, xcodebuild, bitcode

First off, I want to state that without bitcode , **everything is working perfectly.** The problems start when I turn on the "bitcode" flag in the app.

Also, all of the builds are through a CI flow (not manually inside xcode->archive et.al).

The framework is built in a separate flow from the app itself (The app embeds the compiled framework)

I'm getting this error when I try to package the ipa:

> ❌  ld: bitcode bundle could not be generated because
>   '..../Framework.framework/Framework' was built without full bitcode.
>   All frameworks and dylibs for bitcode must be generated from Xcode
>   Archive or Install build for architecture armv7
>
> ❌  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see
>   invocation)

**Regarding the Framework:**

I'm building the framework using the following command: (omitting technical details)

```
# iphone (arm)
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphoneos CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO

# iphone (simulator)
xcodebuild -configuration Release -sdk iphonesimulator CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY="" CODE_SIGNING_REQUIRED=NO
```

and then lipo (FAT binary)

```
lipo -create /Release-iphonesimulator/Framework.framework/Framework -output /Universal/Framework.framework/Framework
```

I've added the compiler flag to the framework to "embed bitcode"

[image]

And I even "validated" it has bitcode per other S.O. questions: ([Compiling iOS library with bitcode enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32868297/compiling-ios-library-with-bitcode-enabled))

> Also, the easiest way to check if the binary contains bitcode is to
>   use otool and grep:
>
> otool -l binary_name | grep __LLVM
>
> you will see one or more segname __LLVM entries if it does have
>   bitcode or empty output if does not.

```
otool -arch arm64 -l Frameworks/Framework.framework/Framework  | grep __LL
segname __LLVM
segname __LLVM
```

I've also tried the other variation of added a compile flag

```
xcodebuild OTHER_CFLAGS="-fembed-bitcode"
```

and had identical error reported to me

Comment: I'm wondering if you were able to resolve this issue? I'm also having the same issue. I ran `otool -arch armv7 -arch armv7s -arch arm64 -l Framework.framework/Framework | grep 'LLVM\|bitcode'` and that return 6 LLVM. But when I tried to Archive, it failed with 'clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1'.

Comment: In one of the comments to the answer in the link you provided, user Mecki indicates that `__bitcode` is a better indicator than `__LLVM` of correct bitcode compilation when checking the output of otool.  Can you or OP check your compilation logs and see whether the `-fembed-bitcode` flag is actually being passed?

Comment: One further note:  in the same comments, user Jonny indicates that he only added the `-fembed-bitcode` compiler flag to the main target, *not* to any of the embedded frameworks themselves, and was successful.

Comment: @fullofsquirrels thanks for replying to the question. here's my univeral build scripts where I'm passing `fembed-bitcode`:

xcodebuild -project ${NAME}.xcodeproj -scheme ${NAME} -configuration 'Release' -sdk iphoneos enable_bitcode=yes -arch arm64 -arch armv7 -arch armv7s only_active_arch=yes OTHER_CFLAGS='-fembed-bitcode' clean build | tee iphoneos.log | xcpretty
xcodebuild -project ${NAME}.xcodeproj -scheme ${NAME} -configuration 'Release' -sdk iphonesimulator10.3 -arch x86_64 -arch i386 only_active_arch=no OTHER_CFLAGS='-fembed-bitcode' clean build | tee iphonesimulator.log | xcpretty

Comment: xcrun lipo -create -output $DIR/${NAME}.framework/${NAME} Build/Products/Release-iphoneos/${NAME}.framework/${NAME} Build/Products/Release-iphonesimulator/${NAME}.framework/${NAME}

Comment: I was finally able to resolve the issue.

Comment: @sonoluminescence Any hints on how were you able to resolve it?

Answer (score 0):

Add BITCODE_GENERATION_MODE=bitcode in the target's build settings as a user defined setting.